# iOS 7 - ContainerView with embedded UITableViewController and UISearchBarController

Tags: layout, xamarin.ios, ios7

I've a simple view which is embedded in an UINavigationController. This view contains a segemented control in it's top bar and a ContainerView as subview.

The content for the ContainerView is a UITableViewController with a UISearchBarController.

[image: Views]
[image: Document Outline left]
[image: Document Outline right]

I've set EdgesForExtendedLayout to none for both controllers.

After first start it looks okey:

After tapping the first time into the search bar - the bar is hidden behind the navigation bar:
[image]

After tapping outside a small part of the search bar is visable (grey border):
[image]

If I drag down then it looks like that:
[image]

After changing the view (push and pop on UINavigationController) it looks like that:
[image]

Any ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want all your view to scroll, and not only the `UITableView`.

I'd embed everything in a `UIScrollView` (segmentedcontrol and tableview), and make sure the tableview doesn't scroll by itself.